# Highstock flag hover state: update font color

Tags: highcharts

I am able to change the fillColor in the highstock flag states property, but I can't find a way to update the fontColor.
What I need is to change the font from black to white, when the mouse hovers over the flag.

Here is my current example, where it doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    chart: {
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        id: 'dataseries',
        data: usdeur
    }, {
        type: 'flags',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 8),
            title: 'C',
            text: 'Shape: "flag"'   
        }],
        color: '#5F86B3',
        fillColor: 'white',
        onSeries: 'dataseries',
        width: 50,
        style: { // text style
            color: 'black'
        },

        states: {
            hover: {
                fillColor: 'orange',
                fontColor: 'white',
                style: {
                    color: 'white'
                },
            }
        }
    }]
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MqV4D/1/

Does anyone have any workarounds for this?
Or can highstock be updated to support this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseover event and CSS function, which will modify color.

http://jsfiddle.net/MqV4D/3/

```
 events:{
                mouseOver:function(){
                    this.data[0].graphic.css({
                        color:'red'
                    });
                },mouseOut:function(){
                    this.data[0].graphic.css({
                        color:'black'
                    });
                }
            },
```